# Unexpected output math.h

Tags: c, math.h

Does anybody knows why this code prints `1000000000000000000` and not `1000000000000000001` as expected?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
   long long n = (pow(10,18) + 1);
   printf("%lld ", n);
}
```

Comment: Hint: what _type_ is the result of `pow()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pow(10, 18)` returns a floating point `double`. The result of that, and adding 1, is indistinguishable in floating point space to the number you get back. For IEEE754, the closest `double` to `1000000000000000001` is `1000000000000000000`, which more than likely accounts for your result.

```
(long long)pow(10, 18) + 1
```

might work (and probably will with a modern C toolset): you are still at the mercy of `pow` returning the algebraically correct result, of which there is no guarantee, although it's becoming increasingly fashionable to regard a C implementation of `pow` that doesn't return the best possible result when given integral arguments as defective - the days of `pow(x, y)` being implemented as simply `exp(y * log(x))` are surely over?

So two options really. Either hope all your target platforms are up to it, or use a mathematics library that has a power function for integral arguments, using a technique such as *exponentation by squaring*.

Comment: are you sure `exp(y * log(x))` should work?

Comment: @Gendozz: It's reasonable but doesn't work well in whole-number applications. It's a nice idea because it's quick. `exp` is trivial for chips to calculate. Natural log is trickier but modern chips can bang it out in a handful of clock cycles.

Comment: I mean i just put those values to my calculator and got different answer: `e^(18×log 10) = 65659969.1373`

Comment: You need to use the *natural* logarithm.